# .NET Core MVC Bootstrap "Collapse" not working

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using it just as described in the docs but I'm not seeing any results. Any ideas?

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="post-details">
    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Title)</h4>
    <p>submitted at @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.CreationDate) by @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.OriginalPoster)</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#postContent" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="postContent">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">comments</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">share</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">hide</button>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="postContent">
    <div class="card card-body">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Content)
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure use **Bootstrap v5.0**,because it used `data-target` instead of `data-bs-target` before `v5.0`:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also, `aria-controls`,`data-bs-target` and `id`are all the same(`postContent`),you need distinguish them like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModel>

@{int i = 0; }        //add this

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <div class="post-details">
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Title)</h4>
        <p>submitted at @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.CreationDate) by @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.OriginalPoster)</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#postContent_@i"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="postContent_@i">
            +
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">comments</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">share</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">hide</button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="postContent_@i">
        <div class="card card-body">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Content)
        </div>
    </div>
    i++;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You're the best! I didn't even realize .NET was shipping an older version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core 3.1 comes with Bootstrap 4 by default.

When you lookup documentation on the Bootstrap site, as of this time, Bootstrap 5 documentation is shown by default.

So when using the Bootstrap documentation, use the appropriate version. See for example, the documentation for `Collapse` in Bootstrap 4:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/

As shown there and as Rena points out, Bootstrap 4 uses `data-toggle` instead of `data-bs-toggle`.

So you may not need to upgrade to Bootstrap 5. I would recommend simply referencing the Bootstrap 4 documentation.